# How to create a tuple of tuples in python?

Tags: python

I want to combine:

```
A = (1,3,5)
B = (2,4,6)
```

into:

```
C = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

Is there a function that does this in python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes:

```py
tuple(zip(A, B))
```

And this is all. The result will be as follows (both in Python 2.x and 3.x):

```py
>>> tuple(zip(A, B))
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
zip((1,3,5),(2,4,6))
```

This will technically return a `list` on python2.x and a iterable object on python3.x.  To get a `tuple` of tuples, you would just enclose the whole thing in `tuple(zip((1,3,5),(2,4,6)))`