# python multidimensional list manipulation

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

I want to convert it to

```
a = [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: very closely related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13367710/748858

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`zip` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), and use `*a` to **[unpack](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)**:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
print zip(*a)
>>> [(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
```

If you want lists instead of tuples:

```
print map(list, zip(*a))
>>> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Answer (score 4):

use `zip`.

```
print zip(*a)
```

If you really want a list of lists, instead of a list of tuple:

```
[list(x) for x in zip(*a)]
```

will do the trick (and, as a bonus, this works the same on python2.x and python3.x)